# How to Calculate unique statuses in a JSON dataset file

Tags: json, python-3.x

I have a dataset of JSON File

```
[
{
    "id": 333831567, 
    "pieceId": 25395616, 
    "status": 10800, 
    "userId": 911, 
    "startTime": 1490989764, 
    "endTime": 1491001113
},
{
    "id": 333883698, 
    "pieceId": 25390812, 
    "status": 10451, 
    "userId": 88738562, 
    "startTime": 1491004450, 
    "endTime": 1491004579
```

The JSON file has over 15000 entries. How do I calculate unique status from this dataset.

Answer (score 2):

**Using pandas**

```
import pandas as pd

# convert your "data" into pandas dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data, orient='columns') 
# count non unique values for status column 
df.loc[: ,'status'].nunique()
```

**Using dictionary comprehension + len() + set()**

```
res = {key: len(set([sub[key] for sub in data ]))
       for key in data[0].keys()}
# prints unique values for each keys in the dictionary
print("Unique count of keys : " + str(res))
# print unique values for status 
print("Unique count of status : " + str(res['status']))
```

**class (object): def unique_statuses_count(self) -> int**
(requirement in comments)

```
class Jsondt:

    def unique_statuses_count(self) :
        res = {key: len(set([sub[key] for sub in self ]))
       for key in self[0].keys()}
        #return unique count for each key in the dataset
        return res


# return unique count for "status" column as integer 
# or choose any othere column present in data
Jsondt.unique_statuses_count(data)['status']
```

Comment: The question requires to respond as shown;                                                                
     class  (object):

    def unique_statuses_count(self) -> int:
        """
        how many unique statuses are in the data set.
       
        """